# Python resize imported SVG

Tags: python, import, dimensions

I'm using python for batch upload and rendering. I need to import many SVGs, resize them and place to required position. Import is OK, curve is named, I can read dimensions, but I can't write new dimensions back. Where I doing mistake? Thanks for help.

```
maxSize = 0.220
for emboss in embosses:
    emb_name = emboss[:-4]
    loadedSVG = bpy.ops.import_curve.svg(filepath = embossDir + emboss, filter_glob=".svg")
    for obj in bpy.data.objects:
        if obj.tag == False:
            obj.name = emb_name
            obj.tag = True
            bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(pattern = emb_name)
            meshes = bpy.context.selected_objects

            x, y, z = meshes[0].dimensions 

            if x > y:
                needRatio = maxSize / x
            if y > x:
                needRatio = maxSize / y

            # not working code starts

            meshes[0].dimensions.x = x * needRatio
            meshes[0].dimensions.y = y * needRatio
            meshes[0].dimensions.z = z * needRatio

            # not working code ends

            bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
```

Answer (score 3):

To change the dimensions use the scale Vector.

```
obj.scale *= needRatio
```

NB: I have a hassle with obj.tag, albeit could be because I am running in UI and not batch mode.

```
# import blender svg logo blender.svg in app folder 
# (quick hack works on linux)
bpy.ops.import_curve.svg(filepath = bpy.app.binary_path + ".svg")
#the list of all objects with obj.tag = False `
false_tag = [o for o in bpy.data.objects if not o.tag]
```

gives me an empty list.

However, it appears the importer doesn't return the objects as selected, hence selecting all objects first then running the op and making a list of all unselected objects in the scene gives me the imported svg's curves could be another way to go.

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.import_curve.svg(filepath = bpy.app.binary_path + ".svg")
newcurves = [c for c in context.scene.objects if not c.select]
```

setting select to True on each curve in newcurves  removes the need to run bpy.ops.object.select again.

Comment: Thanx, batFINGER, it works. I'm using blender as tool for photo-complicated scenes and this solution is great for me.