# Script for rotating multiple selected objects and insert keyframes

Tags: animation, scripting

I'm very new to python scripting so I could use a lot of help.

I'm looking for a script to do these action in sequence:

1) Manually select objects to interact with in the scene
2) Set a specific frame where i want to set my animation keyframe
3) Rotate all objects by 180° on the Z axis 
4) set a LocRotScale Keyframe

and repeat this for about 3 times, so having 3 complete rotations of the objects, splitted by 2 central "stops" of 48 frames.

can someone please help me with this?

until now i have managed to compile the script for rotating and keyframing a single object.

```
import bpy
from math import *  
import mathutils

scene = bpy.data.scenes["Scene"]
scene.frame_start = 1
scene.frame_end = 768

ob = bpy.context.object

bpy.context.scene.frame_set(24) # start with delay

ob.rotation_euler = (0,0,0)

bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type='LocRotScale')

bpy.context.scene.frame_set(120) #half rotation 1

ob.rotation_euler = (0,0,3.14)

bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type='LocRotScale')

bpy.context.scene.frame_set(216) #rotation 1

ob.rotation_euler = (0,0,6.28)

bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type='LocRotScale')

bpy.context.scene.frame_set(264) #stop pause 1

ob.rotation_euler = (0,0,6.28)

bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type='LocRotScale')

bpy.context.scene.frame_set(360) #half rotation 2

ob.rotation_euler = (0,0,9.42)

bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type='LocRotScale')

bpy.context.scene.frame_set(456) #rotation 2

ob.rotation_euler = (0,0,12.56)

bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type='LocRotScale')

bpy.context.scene.frame_set(504) #end stop 2

ob.rotation_euler = (0,0,12.56)

bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type='LocRotScale')

bpy.context.scene.frame_set(600) #half rotation 3

ob.rotation_euler = (0,0,15.7)

bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type='LocRotScale')

bpy.context.scene.frame_set(696) #rotation 3

ob.rotation_euler = (0,0,18.84)

bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type='LocRotScale')

bpy.context.scene.frame_set(744) #end 1

ob.rotation_euler = (0,0,18.84)

bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type='LocRotScale')

bpy.context.scene.frame_set(769) #end 

ob.rotation_euler = (0,0,18.84)

bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type='LocRotScale')
```

Now what i'm tryng to do is to cycle trough all objects in scene and repeat the same actions of rotation and keyframing but I'm not getting much results.

can someone plese provide some help about this?

thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. Could you please present your research, what you have tried, what has failed and what you expected. As is stands, it reads a bit as if you not only have posted multiple questions in a single question post, but also expect someone else to create a script according to your requirements. (This would be volunteer work, not a question-answer exchange.)

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/60238/15543  Don't use the keyframe insert menu, use `ob.keyframe_insert(datapath, frame=frame)`  Also angles in blender are expressed internally as radians.