# Why isnt my code not creating keyframes to all the active objects?

Tags: python, animation, scripting

So im facing issue with my python code which is as follows.

```
objects= ["sphere","cube"]
c_frames=60
for k in objects:
    bpy.data.objects[str(k)].select_set(True)
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active=bpy.data.objects[str(k)]
obj = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active
obj.keyframe_insert("rotation_euler",frame=c_frame)
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=0.151266, orient_axis='X', orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(True, False, False), mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SPHERE', proportional_size=0.318631, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
obj.keyframe_insert("rotation_euler",frame=(c_frame+5))
obj.keyframe_insert("rotation_euler",frame=c_frame+5+10)
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=-0.151266, orient_axis='X', orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(True, False, False), mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SPHERE', proportional_size=0.318631, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
obj.keyframe_insert("rotation_euler",frame=c_frame+5+10+5)
```

For this code blender is selecting both the objects but is creating keyframes only for the cube but not for the sphere. I  want the code to create keyframes for all the objects in the list. Kindly let me know what it is that i'm doing wrong, and what is the way to go about it. Thank you.

Comment: Most likely because your indentation is wrong. Also make sure you are assigning objects in context, replace: `bpy.data.objects[obj_name]` by `bpy.context.scene.objects.get(obj_name)`, related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132825/python-selecting-object-by-name-in-2-8/132829#132829 and I'd suggest get rid of the transform operator if possible, then you don't have to set the active object. How to insert rotation keyframes propperly: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/60238/31447

Comment: Oh i thought we can first select all the objects and then set keyframes to all objects together. Thanks for the comment.