# Selecting curve after importing svg using bpy

Tags: python, import, selection-tools, svg

I'm importing an SVG file into my scene using `bpy`. But after importing, the curve is not selected nor active. Here is wat I am doing:

```
path = '/path/fo/file/'
file = 'contour.svg'

bpy.ops.import_curve.svg(filepath = path + file)
```

Can I just assume that the newly imported object is always the last one in the objects array? So that I can grab it like this:

```
active_object = bpy.context.scene.objects[-1]
```

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store the names of the objects before and after importing and find the difference to make sure you have the latest one:

```
import bpy
C = bpy.context

# Names of all objects before importing the SVG
names_pre_import = set([ o.name for o in C.scene.objects ])

# Import SVG as curve
fp = '/mylocalpath/svgcurve.svg'
bpy.ops.import_curve.svg(filepath = fp)

# Names of all objects after importing the SVG
names_post_import = set([ o.name for o in C.scene.objects ])

# Perform set difference to find the new name and store it
new_object_name = names_post_import.difference( names_pre_import ).pop()

# Reference new object
o = C.scene.objects[ new_object_name ]

# Set as selected and active in Blender 2.7x
o.select = True
C.scene.objects.active = o

# Set as selected and active in Blender 2.8
# o.select_set(True)
# C.view_layer.objects.active = o
```

Comment: Howdy 'Lousky.  Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/48281/15543  This is prob a better way, or patching the importer to make it follow a more default behaviour and return the curves selected. btw Having issues with this addon in 2.8 setting the diffuse color, working ok at your end?

Comment: Thanks @batFINGER. Are you having trouble with the import SVG as curve? I could change the color after importing.

Comment: My 2.8 build the importer is throwing an error when attempting to import blender.svg . Will check I've updated the addon repo correctly on next build.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set an id attribute to each path in your svg file :

```
<!-- test.svg -->
<svg>
  <path id="R" d="M51.91962,15.36299c-2.08408,-0.41842 -4.74969..." />
  <path id="A" d="M96.07288,-0.33042c-0.27285,-1.06773 -0.52182..." />
</svg>
```

Then the curves will be named :

[image]

And so you can select them :

```
o = C.scene.objects[ 'A' ]
o.select_set(True)
C.view_layer.objects.active = o
```